# Tell from PGP signature which algorithms served in its creation

Tags: security, sha, apt, pgp

I am dealing with a Debian repository that apparently contains an `InRelease` file that may have been signed in a way that is [no longer appropriate](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/387053/debian-9-apt-and-gpg-error-inrelease-the-following-signatures-were-inva). The symptom is that clients receive the warning `The repository '... InRelease is not signed` when they run `apt-get update`.

`InRelease` contains sections starting with `-----BEGIN PGP SIGNED MESSAGE-----` and `-----BEGIN PGP SIGNATURE-----`, so it is signed, and I've already adjusted my PGP `personal-digest-preferences` and `personal-cipher-preferences` settings to exclude SHA-1 from use. But something is still lacking.

My question is this: When I inspect the actual signature (the ASCII armor between `----BEGIN PGP SIGNATURE-----` and `-----END PGP SIGNATURE-----`) is there a way to tell which algorithms served in its creation, and specifically whether SHA-1 served in its creation? I guess the answer is no, but I'd like to hear an expert's opinion.

**UPDATE** The first line after `-----BEGIN PGP SIGNATURE-----` reads `Hash: SHA256` so that looks good (since I've chosen `SHA256` first in the preferences settings), but the problem still persists.

**UPDATE** I've now excluded SHA-1 also from indices by calling `apt-ftparchive packages` and `apt-ftparchive release` (for creating files `Packages` and `Releases` respectively) with additional parameters `--no-sha1`, but the problem still persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So now it looks as if the signature was already valid (after removing SHA-1 digests as described), but the signing key was not yet known.

So adding the signing key to clients with `add-key add key.pub` made the problem disappear.